# How to allow users to build their own reports from a shared dataset without having to assign them license?

Tags: powerbi

I have PRO and PREMIUM capacity workspaces. Both these workspaces have datasets.

I want users with no license (free license) to be able to use these dataset and build their own reports in their own `My Workspace`. Is PRO license a must for the report creator to be able to use the datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Free users can really in practice just use their 'My Workspace' to build reports and use their own datasets. As the shared dataset would be an App Workspace, this will require a Pro license, as consuming a dataset from another workspace is classed as collaborating, even if just creating a new report in your My Workspace.